# Vb.net compare two text file and specific line

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am new in vb.net and now i am working on copy line and compare

**example:** Step 1 compare all value line in A.txt with B.txt if B contain A value, value must remove in B
Step 2 after remove we need to copy specific line from A to B like below result
**A.txt:**
Line1 G
Line2 I
Line3 B
Line4 A
Line5 O
**B.txt**
Line1 A
Line2 B
Line3 C
Line4 D
Line5 G
**result in C.txt shold be**
Line1 G
Line2 C
Line3 B
Line4 A
Line5 D

Hope you can give me a solution 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy one. Not sure, if you have done anything till now. But here is the `algorithm` for you to start:

> 1. Read file A into array
> 2. Read File B into array
> 3. Compare array A and Array B. Add unique values to Array C
> 4. Write Array C to a text file.

Once you've written code and have a code specific question, feel free to ask.